# Dudas con Object List

Tags: java, lista, bucle-for, objeto

Tengo dudas, que significa lo siguiente en java

```
for (Object x : objetoList)
```

no estaría entendiendo bien para que es el objeto List con el for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El bucle For Each se usa para iterar los objetos de una lista de 1 en 1

Se divide en 3 partes (si no tenemos la propia declaración del for)

Object: Indica el tipo de objeto que sacas de la lista en este caso si pones Object te dejaría sacar cualquier objeto pero tendrás que lidiar con casteos, yo recomiendo poner el tipo que contiene la lista, así tambien aumentas la facilidad de lectura del código

x: Es el nombre que le das a ese objeto en esa iteración

objetoList: Es la lista de donde sacas esos objetos

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MiObjetoVo> miLista = new ArrayList<MiObjetoVo>();

//llenas tu lista 
//...

//ahora lo iteras con el siguiente For each
for(MiObjetoVo miObjeto : miLista){
  //aquí tu código lo que quieras realizar con tus objetos
  //es objeto por objeto de tu lista
  //comunmente se utiliza para imprimir lo que hay en cada objeto, por ej.
  System.out.println(miObjeto.getNombre());
}
```

Espero te haya quedado claro.
En resumen es una mejor manera de iterar una lista que tiene objetos.
La lista puede ser de tipo de objeto que tu le señales al crearla.